# logic and set theory - subset of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

I want to formally prove that $X\subseteq A\cap B\Leftrightarrow X\subseteq A\wedge X\subseteq B$. This means $\forall x(x\in X\Rightarrow x\in A\wedge x\in B)$. By the use of logic ($P\Rightarrow (Q\wedge R)\equiv (P\Rightarrow Q)\wedge(P\Rightarrow R)$) we get
$$
\forall x((x\in X\Rightarrow x\in A)\wedge (x\in X\Rightarrow x\in B)).
$$
How can we conclude that this implies $\forall x(x\in X\Rightarrow x\in A)\wedge \forall x(x\in X\Rightarrow x\in B)$ (which is $X\subseteq A\wedge X\subseteq B$)?

Comment: Use that the relation $\subset$ is transitive, i.e.: $A \subset B \subset C$ implies $A \subset C$.

Comment: You're not revealing which formal system you're conducting your proof in, but any self-respecting proof system for first-order logic ought to allow you to prove $\forall x(\varphi\land\psi) \to (\forall x.\varphi)\land(\forall x.\psi)$ fairly straightforwardly. The details depend on information you haven't told us, though.

Comment: @HenningMakholm what about union (ie disjunction?)

Comment: @Ivan: What about that?

Comment: consider an element $x\in (A\cap B)$.

by definition of the intersection, we have $(x\in A) \land (x\in B)$.

now consider the collection of all $x$ which fit this criteria

Comment: @HenningMakholm If $X\subseteq A\cup B$, it doesnt mean that $X\subseteq A\vee X\subseteq B$, but if I use similar argument, I would get same thing as above, right?

Comment: @Ivan: A self-respecting proof system _shouldn't_ allow you to prove $\forall x(\varphi\lor\psi)\to(\forall x.\varphi)\lor(\forall x.\psi)$, because that is not valid in general!

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well, are there some resources about this? At the moment, at university, we just started talking about ZF set theory (not much about logic behind it though)

Comment: @Ivan: Are you sure you're actually doing _formal_ proofs? It doesn't really sound like it, based on your comments and your apparent inability to say which formal system your proofs are supposed to be done with.

Comment: @HenningMakholm No, im not sure actually...

Answer (score 2):

$$\forall x (F \wedge G) \vdash \dashv (\forall x (F))\wedge(\forall x(G))$$
So you already have what you need!

Just keep in mind that thiw is not the case with $\vee$ since
$$\forall x (F \vee G) \not \vdash  (\forall x (F))\vee(\forall x(G))$$

Comment: @Ivan: If you're not familiar with formal systems, just use common sense first. The first statement in this answer states that conjunction under a universal quantifier is equivalent to conjunction of the statements separately universally quantified. Why? Because if every object satisfies two properties $P,Q$, then surely every object satisfies $P$ and every object satisfies $Q$, and vice versa. This is obviously not the case for disjunction. Simple counter-example: everything is either a rock or not a rock, but that does not imply that either everything is a rock or everything is not a rock!

Comment: @Ivan: But you might benefit greatly from reading the books I recommend at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684208.