# Is this set of formula consistent?

Tags: first-order-logic

Assume that $P$ is a 1-place predicate. We define the set of formulas $\Gamma$ like this:
$$\Gamma =\{\lnot \forall x_0 P(x_0),P(x_0),P(x_1),P(x_2),...\}.$$

Is $\Gamma $ consistent?

My answer is no, and my deduction is that it is obvious that $\Gamma \vdash \forall x P(x)$ and also $\Gamma \vdash \lnot\forall x P(x)$ so $\Gamma \vdash \bot$, so it is inconsistent, but how can I deduce the part that $\Gamma \vdash \forall x P(x)$?
I think it's obvious but I can't prove it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Using natural deduction, assume $\neg\forall x P(x)$, then there exists $x_0$ such that $\neg P(x_0)$, but you can find $P(x_0)$ in $\Gamma$, so you've found a contradiction.

Comment: "it is obvious that $Γ⊢∀xP(x)$..." can you write the derivation ?

Comment: what are $x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots$ ?

Comment: As $P(x_i)$ is a member of $\Gamma$ for all $i$ so the result will be derived naturally ,but this is exactly my problem,how to deduce this result?

Comment: We need some details... what about the def of *consistency* ? Is it "equivalent" to *satisfiable* ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes it is.

Comment: @Javi Could you please tell the deduction of "..¬∀xP(x) , then there exists x0 such that ¬P(x0).."?

Comment: $\Gamma$ is *satisfiable*; consider a domain $D= \{ 0,1 \}$ and interpret $P$ with $\{ 0 \}$. Then consider a variable assignment function $s$ such that $s(x_i)=0$ for every $i$. Clearly $D,s \vDash \Gamma$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but P is a one place predicate,not a function.

Comment: And thus ? The "meaning" assigned to $P$ is a subset of the domain, and this is the way we have to interpret unary predicates.

Comment: Techincal question/comment: In $\neg \forall x_0 P(x_0)$ the $x_0$ is used as a variable, but in $P(x_0)$ it is used as a constant ... Which is it?  Are $x_0, x_1, ...$ all constants?  And if so, would you be ok with changing $\neg \forall x_0 P(x_0)$ to $\neg \forall x P(x)$?

Comment: @Bram28 I was thinking about this too,I'm not sure if we can do this,and $x_i$ are individual variables.

Comment: @MAh2014 But if $x_i$ is a variable, then $P(x_i)$ is not a statement to which we can assign a truth-value. Hence, $\Gamma$ is not a set of sentences of which we can determine its consistency.  So, for your question to make sense, we really need to regard all $x_i$ to be constants ... but we'll also need to change $\forall x_0 P(x_0)$ to $\forall x P(x)$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't have any idea about Bram28 question,would you please help?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I can't understand what is $s$,we can't assign any thing to individual variables?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonable interpretation of **consistency** of a set of formulae is that one cannot prove a contradiction from them, which is then equivalent to **satisfiability**, which means existence of a **model**, which must assign every free variable to an object. It is certainly possible to satisfy $Γ$ as given, since one could construct a structure with just two objects, such that one of them satisfies $P$ and the other does not, and in this structure assign all free variables $x_0,x_1,...$ to the one object that satisfies $P$.

If you're not familiar with this terminology, refer to Wolfgang Rautenberg's *Concise Introduction to Logic* or Stephen Simpson's notes as linked from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1684208/21820).

Comment: Thank you so much,I understood it completely.

Comment: @MAh2014: You're welcome!