# Is "Propositional Calculus" by P. H. Nidditch a good introduction to logic?

Tags: logic

I have looked at several books on line regarding logic.  Some, though they say they beginning books, are not as far I am concerned, as they launch into elaborate symbology without explanation. This one, *Propositional Calculus*, by P. H. Nidditch from 1962 seems to be more my level.  I find that I can understand the author, which is a more than I can say for any other book I have tried.  It is, perhaps, because it is simple.  I do not know if this is a good book to put my time into, as I do not know where it leads.  I do not have any particular goals in studying logic, but I do not want to put time into something that then has be unlearned.  Is this a good book to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [Stanford Universities Intro to Logic](http://intrologic.stanford.edu/public/lessons.php) for self study of symbolic logic, and [Greg Restall's short lecture series](https://blogs.unimelb.edu.au/logic/2016/04/13/logic-videos/) course if you want to learn from a lecture series instead. I have personally completed Stanford's entire course, and Greg Restall's Introductory Logic.

There are several places on stack exchange that already exist recommending logic textbooks. One such example is user21820's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577114/what-are-the-prerequisites-for-studying-mathematical-logic/1684208#1684208), which has been a very good reference for me in the past.

I cannot vouch for Propositional calculus, by P. H. Nidditch, as this book is behind a paywall for me, and my university library doesn't have it either. I would caution learning exclusively from older books however, as they will most likely not include modern content, such as automated theorem proving.

*Edit:* I just went through Propositional calculus, by P. H. Nidditch with the link you provided, and it is an excellent book. However I think it would be a poor one to learn from as a first textbook for a number of reasons.

- The notation is bespoke. This means it will be hard to
  ask questions regarding the text.
- The axioms of its deductive system all involve implication. This will lead to a certain way of thinking that is uncommon. It is not necessarily bad, but you may have trouble describing your mathematical problems to other people if you always think in implications.
- The textbook only covers completeness. It does not include incompleteness.

The textbook has a lot going for it if you can get over the quirks. It is very concise and I appreciate the author proving every theorem rather than just stating them.

In short, it is a textbook I would like to read myself, but not one I would recommend to new students.

Comment: Thank you for the insight.  Should it be of use to you, here is the site where you can read Nidditch and other books:  https://archive.org/index.php

Comment: I just edited my post after going through Propositional calculus, by P. H. Nidditch. I like the textbook but wouldn't recommend it to new students. The best introduction I can recommend is Stanford Universities, and then Greg Restall's short lecture series if you want to cover incompleteness.