# Topology - Every injective quotient map is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, logic, solution-verification

I am going to show that every injective quotient map is a homeomorphism:

Let $(X,\tau_{X})$, $(Y,\tau_{Y})$ be topological spaces.

Definitions:

$q:X \rightarrow Y$ is a quotient map iff $q$ is surjective ($q[X] = Y$) and
$$
\forall V\subseteq Y: V\in \tau_{Y} \iff q^{-1}[V] \in \tau_X
$$
where $[]$ is used to denote the image of a function. $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism iff $f$ is bijective and
$$
\forall U\subseteq X: U\in \tau_{X} \iff f[U] \in \tau_Y
$$

Lemma:
$$\forall x \forall y: P(x,y) \implies Q(x)$$
is equivalent to
$$\forall x: Q(x) \land \forall x \exists y: P(x,y)$$

Proof of the lemma: [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3916409/logic-reducing-a-first-order-logic-involving-a-material-conditional)

Proof:

It is sufficient to show that if $q$ is injective, $\forall V\subseteq Y: V\in \tau_{Y} \iff q^{-1}[V] \in \tau_X$ is equivalent to $\forall U\subseteq X: U\in \tau_{X} \iff q[U] \in \tau_Y$.

Notes:
Injectivity of $q$ ensures $q^{-1}[q[U]] = U$ for all $U \subseteq X$.
For a surjection $q$, $\forall V \subseteq Y: \exists U \subseteq X: q[U] = V$ is a logical necessity.

$$
\begin{align}
&\forall V\subseteq Y: V\in \tau_{Y} \iff q^{-1}[V] \in \tau_X& \\
&\iff
(\forall V\subseteq Y: V\in \tau_{Y} \iff q^{-1}[V] \in \tau_X) \land (\forall V \subseteq Y: \exists U \subseteq X: q[U] = V)& \text{Tautology}\\
&\iff
\forall V\subseteq Y : \forall U \subseteq X: q[U] = V \implies V\in \tau_{Y} \iff q^{-1}[V] \in \tau_X & \text{Lemma}\\
&\iff
\forall U \subseteq X: \forall V\subseteq Y : q[U] = V \implies q[U]\in \tau_{Y} \iff q^{-1}[q[U]] \in \tau_X &p \rightarrow q \iff p\rightarrow p \land q\\
&\iff
\forall U \subseteq X: \forall V\subseteq Y : q[U] = V \implies q[U]\in \tau_{Y} \iff U \in \tau_X & \text{Injectivity}\\
&\iff
(\forall U\subseteq X : q[U]\in \tau_{Y} \iff U \in \tau_X) \land (\forall U \subseteq X:\exists V \subseteq Y: q[U] = V) &\text{Lemma}\\
&\iff
\forall U\subseteq X : q[U]\in \tau_{Y} \iff U \in \tau_X& \text{Tautology}\\
\end{align}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't understand the lemma and how it's used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but it is difficult to understand and unnecessarily complicated.

Your lemma is a purely logical statement, and it is unusual to begin a concrete proof with such a statement. In fact, all arguments are based on logic, and we must take that foundation as granted. Otherwise every proof would have to begin with an explanation of all logical, set theoretical  etc. issues.

The essence of your arguments it this:

1. Any quotient map $q$ is a continuous surjection.
2. Any injective quotient map $q$ is a continuous bijection. Thus it suffices to show that if $U \in \tau_X$, then $p(U) \in \tau_Y$. But this is obvious since $p^{-1}(p(U)) = U$ for injective maps.